# Customizing ADB2C Login Page with Forgot ‘UserName’ link

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I’ve implemented a user login page using ADB2C custom html template. Once user initiates a login, b2c signin userflow triggers the unified.html and displays a login UI successfully. During login user will use username field which is a unique attribute.

There is a use case to show an “forgot UserName” link in the signin page, along with the “forgot Password”  link.  Any suggestions to handle this forgot UserName link usecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset).

This shows adding "Forgot password" as a button, not a link.

So you could add another button for "Forgot username" and that would then kick off the forgot username flow in the same manner.

Comment: Given forgot password link reference explains to handle the forgot password link in the signin page. But I’m trying to implement a new flow in the login page for “Forgot UserName”? Any thoughts on implementing this flow in b2c?

Comment: I agree. Instead of passing the fact that the password was forgotten back to the application, it calls a technical profile within the custom policy. I'm suggesting you do the same with "Forgot username". Another way of looking at it is by replacing the Facebook button with "Forgot username". So clicking the button invokes a TP where you e.g. if you had MFA, you could ask the user to verify their email address and then do a read by email address and get the user's username and email it.

Comment: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-discovery

Comment: Sure, with this approach might helps to handle this usecase.